# Хранение и поиск в графе

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, графы

Имеется некая игра. Необходимо оптимально быстро найти кратчайшую последовательность ходов для достижения перехода из одного игрового состояния в другое. (или всевозможные последовательности определённой длины). При чём нужна будет функция возможности ограничения возможных ходов. Например, если возможных ходов 4 (влево, вправо, вверх, вниз), то мы моглы бы запросить путь, который, допустим, не использует ходы влево и вниз. Как всё это дело лучше хранить и какие алгоритмы использовать для поиска?

**[Размышления]** Представляю себе принцип примерно следующим образом... При каждом ходе строится граф, где ребро это ход, а узел это состояние игры после данного хода (т.е. можно будет как анализировать существующую игру, так и сгенерировать до определённой глубины всевозможные 'виртуальные' комбинации для поиска по ним). Направление хода это вес, видимо. Но я не припомню ни одного стандартного алгоритма, который исключал бы из поиска определённые веса... Т.е. нужно пробежаться по графу и проставить исключаемым ходам неприлично высокий вес? (что тоже не исключает его участие на 100%) Или лучше подправить алгоритм, чтобы он по списку игнорировал определённые веса, а сам граф воспринимал, как невзвешенный?

На входе алгоритма - некие состояния игры, т.е. для каждого узла нужно хранить какой-то хеш (т.к. хранить все состояния довольно накладно), чтобы входные данные сразу можно было ассоциировать с нужными узлами графа. А потом поиском кратчайшего пути (A* наверное будет в данном случае оптимально?) можно будет найти кратчайший, а поиском вглубину(?) с ограничением по глубине для определённой длины.

Comment: `При каждом ходе строится граф, где ребро это ход, а узел это состояние игры после данного хода` - `При чём нужна будет функция возможности ограничения возможных ходов` не создавайте при ходе ребра, которые вам не нужны. И тогда весов не надо, граф не будет взвешенным

Comment: я бы просто во время поиска пути строил граф - то есть строил только те узлы, которые могут понадобиться. Например, возьмем состояние А. Вы же знаете возможные ходы из этого состояния с учетом ограничений. Строите все ходы из A в B1, B2, ...Bn. Потом из каждого Bi строите ходы в C1...Cn, то есть такой поиск в ширину. Ну и стройте пока не попадете в нужное состояние O, как попадете - возвращайтесь из O --> A, это и будет кратчайший путь

Comment: В качестве преждевременной оптимизации :) Можно делать 2 поиска одновременно, один из A, другой из O, ну и искать момент, когда какая то вершина будет обработана двумя алгоритмами.

Comment: @tym32167 `ну и искать момент` сдаётся мне поиск этого момента съест всю идею `преждевременной оптимизации` )

Comment: почему? у вас же есть состояние - это узел. У узла считайте хеш. Ведите 2 хештаблицы посещенных узлов, одна для каждого поиска. Когда очередной узел в поиске 1 уже содержится в хештаблице поиска 2, то момент настал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это все решается через А*, как ни странно. А* предназначен для нахождения маршрутов по графу между вершинами.

Берете стартовое состояние игры (входная вершина) и проходите все возможные переходы (ребра графа), проходите по ним, получаете новые состояния (вершины). Проверяете не совпадают ли вершины с ранее известными, и объединяете их. К каждой вершине записываете минимальную "цену" её достижения из стартовой вершины. Повторяете рекурсивно, каждый раз выбирая вершину с наименьшей "ценой", до тех пор пока одна из вершин не будет целевым состоянием игры. В процессе построения графа, следите за своими правилами и проверяете из какого состояния (вершины) они дают перейти в другое или нет. Т.е. другими словами, ребра переходов могут быть однонаправленными.

---

> Направление хода это вес, видимо.

Нет. Направление - это существование односторонней связи (ребра). Ребра могут быть односторонними, это нормально.

> На входе алгоритма - некие состояния игры, т.е. для каждого узла нужно хранить какой-то хеш

Можно хэш, это ускорит поиск одинаковых состояний в большом графе.

Comment: А если граф может иметь большое количество вершин с возможным 1-6 количеством рёбер из каждой, то для хранения, как я понимаю, лучше использовать список смежности?

Comment: Если у вас не десятки тысяч вершин, и не полсотни ребер из каждой, то особой разницы в выборе способа хранения нет. Делайте как удобнее. Все равно в итоге, у вас список вершин отсортированный по "цене" и вы каждый раз берете верхнюю, обходите и заносите ее соседей с "ценами" в этот список. И повторяете до победного.

Comment: вершин может и десятки тысяч, а то и сотни... но рёбер мало из каждой. Я в том смысле, что при малом количестве рёбер матрица смежности будет есть неоправданно много памяти?

Comment: Матрицу смежности я бы при любом раскладе не использовал. Удобнее же хранить смежности списком в каждой вершине (и однонаправленность связей так аккуратнее задается, просто наличием или отсутствием ссылки). Все равно доступ к памяти будет почти случайным по мере перебора вершин.